How can I draw a simple house?
I am trying to draw this picture

I tried
Graphics3D[{Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {6, 8, 4}] }, Boxed -> False]



cbd = {{0, 0, 0}, {6, 8, 4}};
roof = {{0, 0, 4}, {0, 8, 4}, {0, 4, 6.3}, {6, 0, 4}, {6, 8, 4}, {6, 
    4, 6.3}};
base = Graphics3D[{Line[{{6, 4, 4}, {6, 4, 6.3}}], 
   Line[{{6, 3.8, 4}, {6, 4, 4}, {6, 4, 4.2}, {6, 3.8, 4.2}, {6, 3.8, 
      4}}],
   Text[Rotate["2.3 m", -Pi/2], {6, 4, 5.15}, {-2, 0}],
   Text[Rotate["6 m", -Pi/2], {3, 0, 0}, {2.5, 0}],
   Text["8 m", {6, 4, 0}, {0, 2}],
   Text["4 m", {6, 8, 2}, {-2, 0}], Opacity[0]
   , Cuboid @@ cbd, Prism[roof]}, Boxed -> False]




A starting point,similar with https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/305946/72111

Clear[polys, polyhedron];
polys = {Polygon[{{0, 0}, {8, 0}, {8, 4}, {0, 4}}], 
   Polygon[{{8, 4}, {4, 4 + 2.3}, {0, 4}}]};
polyhedron = RegionProduct[#, Line[{{0}, {6.}}]] & /@ polys;
DynamicModule[{point = 10 {Cos[1.9], .5, Sin[1.9]}, 
  vertical = {0, 1, 0}, angle = 8 Degree}, 
 Overlay[Graphics3D[#, Lighting -> {{"Ambient", White}}, 
     Boxed -> False, ViewPoint -> Dynamic@point, 
     ViewVertical -> Dynamic@vertical, 
     ViewAngle -> Dynamic@angle] & /@ {{EdgeForm[
      AbsoluteThickness[3]], 
     polyhedron}, {EdgeForm[
      Directive@{AbsoluteThickness[2], 
        AbsoluteDashing[{1, 6}, 0, "Round"]}], FaceForm[], polyhedron,
      Thick, Line[{{4, 4 + 2.3, 6}, {4, 4, 6}}], 
     Line[{{4, 4 + .3, 6}, {4 + .3, 4 + .3, 6}, {4 + .3, 4, 6}}]}}, 
  All, 1]]



+1 . Like RegionProduct and Overlay. Very nice. :)

p1 = Prism[{{0, 0, 4}, {0, 8, 4}, {0, 4, 4 + 2.3}, {6, 0, 4}, {6, 8, 
     4}, {6, 4, 4 + 2.3}}];
c1 = Cuboid[{0, 0, 0}, {6, 8, 4}];
Graphics3D[{Transparent, p1, c1}
 , Boxed -> False
 , Axes -> True
 , AxesEdge -> Automatic
 ]



For more advanced sketching, see Graphics3DSketch function available at the Wolfram Function Repository.
